# Memory efficiency when needing to do matrix operations

Tags: c++, class, matrix

I am working on Physics research and have taken an introductory course in C++.  For my research I need to do calculations on very large matrices of the order 3N x 3N and multiplying them together, where N could be over 100.  I have made a working code using multi-dimensional arrays, but when I am reading the data from the file(it is a very large file), the program crashes and I know that it works with smaller matrices because I have tested it.  I was looking around online and a lot of people were mentioning using classes for matrices in C++, but is this more efficient?  And, I didn't go over classes in my C++ class, so I have been reading some tutorials online, but I can't seem to grasp how they would help with matrices.  So, if they were more efficient then multi-dimensional arrays, could someone post a small example of a code with a class of matrices just so I can see how to do it. Thanks

Comment: Search the web for "C++ FAQ Matrix" which will give an example of a matrix class.

Answer (score 1):

You had a C++ course without classes?! It's **the** feature why it evolved from C. A working name was "C with classes". Every good C++ library with matrices will make heavy use of them and templates.

If you use it for research I would really recommend using a library. You only have to learn how to use it and can rely on correctness and best efficiency.

There are plenty and I can't really recommend one as I never had to use one that would fit your purpose, but I heard [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) would be good in solving stuff.

Comment: I have used Eigen and would say that it is a good library to use (and header only, too!).  There is a good discussion of C++ linear algebra libraries [here](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/351/recommendations-for-a-usable-fast-c-matrix-library/353#353).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use `std::vector` instead of arrays.

The problem with arrays is that you need to know the size before hand.  For large or huge arrays, you may need to allocate them from dynamic memory rather than declaring them as static or global.  Some compilers have a limit on the amount of global memory.

The `std::vector` will grow on demand without you having to worry about resizing an array.